# Make Asynchronous GET/POST request in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http-get

I have write this class for make GET request

```
    class GETReq{
func HTTPsendRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {  (data, response, error) -> Void in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        callback("", error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        callback(NSString(data: data,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
    }   

func HTTPGet(url: String, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    HTTPsendRequest(request, callback) }
}
```

In another class called "ManageData"

```
class ManageData{

    func makeTheRequest()->String{
        var makeReq:GETReq=GETReq();
        var ret:String="";

        makeReq.HTTPGet("http://www.example.com/fileExample.php") { (data:String, error:String?) -> Void in
            if(error==nil){ ret="error"; } else { ret="ok"; }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The problem is when in the ViewController class make

```
 var result:String =  manageData.makeTheRequest();
```

the "result" variable is always empty because the makeTheRequest function return the "ret" before completing the get request.

Comment: The `HTTPGet` function is using a trailing closure because it is performing the request asynchronously via `HTTPSendRequest`. Thus, the `makeTheRequest` function cannot just return the data, but rather it should also employ a completion closure like `HTTPSendRequest` did.

Comment: Ok, but how can I make this?

Comment: It's precisely the same closure pattern you used elsewhere. See below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have `makeTheRequest` adopt the same completion closure pattern you use elsewhere. So change `makeTheRequest` to not return any value, but rather take a `callback` parameter which is a closure that will be called when the request finishes:

```
func makeTheRequest(callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
    var makeReq:GETReq=GETReq();
    var ret:String="";

    makeReq.HTTPGet("http://www.example.com/fileExample.php", callback)
}
```

And you'd presumably call this like so:

```
makeTheRequest() { string, error in 
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
        return
    }

    // if you got here, you can use `string`

    println(string)
}
```